# DBeaver (community) chatGPT extension not installing

Tags: dbeaver

I'm trying to install chatgpt extension to Dbeaver community edition 23.0.2 and it doesn't let me pass the second screen. I go 'Help'-'Install new software'->search for GPT->found it->select it->press 'next' it does smth in the background, goes to second screen and I see 'next' button inactive so I can only press 'finish' and 'cancel' both exit installation and that's it. Tried to examine all options by clicking here and there, but no luck.

What's wrong with my installation?
Thanks.